# decimalformat versus string.format

Tags: java, string, format, decimalformat

With string.format introduced in Java 5, is decimalformat now obsolete?  I'm having a hard time finding something you can do in decimalformat that you can't do in string.format.

Answer (score 1):

Using decimalformat is preferable as it have Locale and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

String.format is a static method call but you can create a DecimalFormat instance and reuse a previously specified format.

Answer (score 0):

There is some stuff like automatic promilles and currency symbol substitution. But it is nothing that you can't do better with proper localisation of your own.